# How to get albums from mediastore in Android Q?

Tags: android, mediastore

I am trying to get Images and videos from Media store (album wise).It is working properly in devices having OS version < 10. In Android Q i am getting an syntax error.

```
System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "GROUP": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT _id, _data, date_modified, bucket_display_name, media_type FROM files WHERE ((is_pending=0) AND (is_trashed=0) AND (volume_name IN ( 'external_primary' ))) AND ((media_type=1 OR media_type=3) GROUP BY (bucket_display_name)) ORDER BY bucket_display_name ASC
```

I am using below code to get data.

```
 Uri queryUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
            Uri intqueryUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("internal");

            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE};

            // Return only video and image metadata.
            String selection;



                selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                        + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE
                        + " OR "
                        + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                        + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;


            Cursor cursorExternal,cursorInternal;

                cursorExternal = getContentResolver().query(queryUri, projection, selection+") GROUP BY (bucket_display_name",
                        null, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");
                cursorInternal = getContentResolver().query(intqueryUri, projection, selection+") GROUP BY (bucket_display_name",
                        null, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");



            Cursor cursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[]{cursorExternal, cursorInternal});


            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
                album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME));

                    Log.w( "album:** ",album+"" );

                    HashMap<String, String> listData = Function.mappingInboxAlbum(album, path, countPhoto);

                    if (!albumList.contains(listData)) {

                        albumList.add(listData);
                    }


            }
            cursor.close();
```

I googled it but not getting any solution.
Please help...

Comment: Have you got answer? if yes please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in AndroidManifest :

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I tried with the same code and this line in Manifest. with Targetsdkversion 32

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

first you will need the album_id

```
        Uri path = Uri
                .parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        Bitmap bmp = Album.getAlbumart(getActivity(), Long.parseLong(album_id), path);
```

then

```
    public Bitmap getAlbumart(Context context, long album_id, Uri sArtworkUri) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver()
                .openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        if (pfd != null) {
            FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return bm;
}
```

finally to display use Glide library

```
             try {
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(uri)
                    .asbitmap
                    .error(Glide.with(ivcircle).load(R.drawable.playlist))
                    .into(ivcircle);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> you can use this method

```
 public static ArrayList<Album> loadAlbum(Context context) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    ArrayList<Album> albumList = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[]
            {
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS
            };

    //String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM + " ASC";
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM));
            String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST));
            int numberOfSongs = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS));

            // Save to albumList
            albumList.add(new Album(title, artist, numberOfSongs));
        }
    }
    assert cursor != null;
    cursor.close();
    return albumList;
}
```